# Swift: why use local constant instead of object property?

Tags: swift

I'm starting to wrap my head around Swift but I feel like I'm missing something here. The project template in XCode for Core Data creates a local constant to refer to an object property as per below. Is there some compelling reason for creating the constant instead of referring to the property directly?

```
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil

    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext

    if managedObjectContext != nil {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
            // error handling, etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some compelling reason for creating the constant instead of referring to the property directly?

Three reasons: **brevity/clarity**, **efficiency**, and **safety**.

Using a temporary variable in place of the property makes the code less cluttered, easier to read.

It also avoids a number of superfluous calls to the property accessor.

Finally, it's safer. The code retrieves the context and then compares it to `nil`. If you used separate property accesses, you *might* get different values back each time. Consider:

```
if self.managedObjectContext != nil {
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !self.managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
        // error handling, etc...
    }
}
```

This code could pass the check for `nil`, but the `managedObjectContext` property could change. It *shouldn't*, and changing the context willy-nilly is likely to cause other problems, but if you're going to check a value it's best to keep using *that* value and not introduce the possibility of inadvertently using some *other* value.

Comment: The given example lacks brevity - "if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {" would have saved a superfluous line!

Comment: Thanks, those are fair points. It does seem, though, that adding lines of code and creating extra pointers makes the brevity and efficiency considerations a bit of a wash either way.

To your point, a well-formed property _should_ return consistently and in a thread-safe manner. This feels a bit like adding a safety net for poorly-formed code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's for brevity. Objects are reference types in Swift, not value types, so they are not copied into a new memory location, so using `managedObjectContext` is just so you don't have to keep typing `self.managedObjectContext` over and over again.

Comment: The `self.` is optional in Swift, so less typing does not apply.

Comment: Well, it's not _always_ optional, but it is inferred most of the time. The times where it is not optional is such as in an initializer when a parameter name is the same as a property name, or when you are accessing instance properties from within a closure.

Comment: In this case, it would make more sense for brevity to say `let moc = managedObjectContext`. But with Xcode's auto-complete, the number of keystrokes saved is negligible; it would be for readability at that point.